# How to merge HDF files created by Vaex

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, vaex

I have thousands of HDF files which is around 30GB in total.
The HDF files are created though Vaex, but the name and number of columns of each file are not the same.
I want combine them to a single HDF file and the same dataframe, is there any solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are on disk, you can do something like

```
df = vaex.open_many(list_of_filepaths)
```

Alternatively if your file names are named according to some pattern, for example: `part1.hdf5`, `part2.hdf5`, etc.. you can do something:

```
# Supports glob expressions
df = vaex.open(part*.hdf5)
```

After that you can use `df.export(...)` to export to a single HDF5 file.